# How to implement 'Like' of a feed list in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I have a Feed list, which pass the feed object as `props` to the child.

```
//Feedlist.jsx

render : function(){
   var list = this.state.feeds.map(function(feed){
      <Feed feed={feed} addLike= /> 
   });
   return <div>{list}</div>
},
addLike : function(){
    // Sending the '/like/:feedid' request to server
    // update the whole feed list after callback
    ...
}
```

and here is the Feed component with a like button

```
//Feed.jsx

render : function(){
  return <div>
     <div>this.props.feed.content</div>
     <LikeButton addLike={this.props.addLike} />
  <div>
}

//LikeButton.jsx
render : function(){
   var className = this.props.isLike ? "likeBtn active" : "likeBtn";
   return <div className={className} onClick={this.addLike}></div>
}
```

When the "like" button is clicked, the `active` class would be added to the button.

But all the feeds are rendered by the static `props` from top to bottom. Do I have to trigger a callback from bottom to top to make this change happen?

I don't think the parent(feed list) should response child's logic. The like button component should maintain its own logic. But I don't know how to encapsulate it.

Comment: It's better to have a shared model, observable, or flux store which the child can trigger an action/set something to, and the parent can receive an event that it happened

Answer (score 0):

Use state for the LikeButton and in addLike use setState. You can still pass the button action to the parent but like you say the like button component should maintain its own logic.